# Positional Argument TypeError python tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'd like to run same thing with clickable button and keybind Return. Is this possible? I keep getting same error as you can see below:

When I remove `self.bind` then it works as it should.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: search_button() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Search(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)

        self.bind("<Return>", self.search_button)

        self.search_bar = Frame(self, bg="blue")
        self.search_bar.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
        self.index = Frame(self, width=100)
        self.index.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.content = Frame(self, bg="red")
        self.content.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X)
        self.status_bar = Frame(self, bg="green")
        self.status_bar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

        self.entry = Entry(self.search_bar)
        self.entry.pack(side=LEFT, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.search = Button(self.search_bar, text="Search", command=self.search_button)
        self.search.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.content = Label(self.content, text="DUPA")
        self.content.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.status_bar = Label(self.status_bar, text="DUPA")
        self.status_bar.pack(side=LEFT)

    def search_button(self):
        (self.entry.get())
        if self.entry.get() == 'example1':
            print("lorem ipsum")
```

Comment: The line consisting solely of `(self.entry.get())` is unnecessary, by the way: all it does is return a string, then immediately throw it away.

Comment: Thanks for tip. Unnecessary line deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`search_button()` needs to be able to take the `event` arg from the bind:

```
def search_button(self, event=None):
        (self.entry.get())
        if self.entry.get() == 'example1':
            print("lorem ipsum")
```